# Route redirecting to wrong view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, routes

I am quite stuck and can't figure out where i am going wrong.

I have created routes for /barcodes and a barcodeController with some methods.

When i hit the /barcode route it seems to go to a 404 page that is setup rather than returning some text.

Can someone see why this is happening? 
Logically this should work?

Here is the code....

routes.php -

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'barcodes'), function()
{
   Route::any('/', array('as' => 'barcodes.home', 'uses' => 'BarcodesController@home'));
   Route::any('/{page?}/{seg1?}/{seg2?}', array('uses' => 'BarcodesController@index'));
});
```

BarcodesController.php

```
class BarcodesController extends FrontEndController {

public function __construct()
{
  Parent::__construct();
  new ContentController;
}


public function index($page = null, $sub_page = null, $id = null)
{
  $keepPage = '/'.$page;
  $page = str_replace('-', '_', $page);
  $sub_page = str_replace('-', '_', $sub_page);
  if (method_exists($this, $page))
{
  return $this->$page($sub_page, $id);
}
else if (SitesPages::pageExists($keepPage))
{
  return View::make('sites.default.page');
}
else
{
  return View::make('errors.404');
}
}


public function home()
{
   if (\Reuest::segment(3) == "")
    {
      return "barcodes";
    }
     else{
       return "sitesbarcodes";
    }
 }

 public function howto()
 {
     return View::make('sites.barcodes.howto');
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Can you confirm it's showing your custom 404 page or default one?

Comment: It is showing custom 404 when hitting route /barcodes

Answer (score 0):

Your route `'/barcode'` seem to be entering the /{page?}/{seg1?} route, but it's not able to find the method `'barcodes'` as per your route definitions.

Comment: So what are you suggesting?